# what does the error mean by TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, csv, crud

I am trying to export my data in my react app to a CSV file format when clicking on my export data button but when i click on the button i get this error message for these too.

```
  34 | 
  35 |      for(var i=0; i < A.length; ++i) 
  36 |      {
> 37 |        csvRow.push(A[i].join(","))
     | ^  38 |      }
  39 |      var csvString=csvRow.join("%0A");
  40 |
```

and an error on my button side:

```
  81 |           { this.tabRow() }
  82 |         </tbody>
  83 |       </table>
> 84 |       <button onClick={() => {this.exportCsv()}}>Export Data</button>
     | ^  85 |     </div>
  86 |   );
  87 | }
```

here is the full code of my exportCsv().

```
exportCsv() {
      var csvRow=[];
      var A = [['person', 'business', 'date', 'activity', 'hours', 'learningStatement']];
      var re = this.state.csvData;

      for(var item=0; item<re.length; item++) 
      {
        A.push([item, re[item].person], re[item].business, re[item].date, re[item].activity, re[item].hours, re[item].learningStatement);
      }
      // console.log(A);

      for(var i=0; i < A.length; ++i) 
      {
        csvRow.push(A[i].join(","))
      }
      var csvString=csvRow.join("%0A");

      var a=document.createElement("a");
      a.href='data:attachment/csv.' + csvString;
      a.target='_Blank';
      a.download= 'testfile.csv';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    };
```

this is my csvData state:

```
 csvData: [
          {
            'personName': '',
            'businessName': '',
            'date': '',
            'activity': '',
            'hours': '',
            'learningStatement': ''
          }
```

i haven't dealt with pulling CSV reports from React, so i have no idea how to go farward to fixing it.

Comment: It means that where you are trying to join is not an array

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: Try changing to `A.length - 1, i++` in your for loop. I think its going past the end of your array and then breaking when the index doesnt exist

Comment: i don't get that error anymore but now when i click on the button the browser freaks out and freezes, the screen goes light gray and says paused in Debugger

Comment: Can you console log after the for loop and see if the browser is having trouble with something after it or if the for loop is still an issue?

Comment: i get this:Line 37:7:  Nested block is redundant  no-lone-blocks

Comment: Can you post an example of your `csvData` state value in your question? With that info the code should be completely reproducible for me and others

Comment: This is what i get in my debugger console:
var csvRow=[]; csvRow = Array(22302822),
var A = [['person', 'business', 'date', 'activity', 'hours', 'learningStatement']]; A = (7) [Array(6), Array(2), undefined, "", "", "", ""], var re = this.state.csvData; re = undefined, for(var item=0; item<re.length; item++) item = undefined, re = undefined

Comment: Should this line `A.push([item, re[item].person], ...;` actually be `A.push([item, re[item].person, ... re[item].learningStatement]);`? with the bracket moved to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different issues that are mostly related to how loops and array functions work. I was able to get it to work correctly with the following changes:

Moving the bracket after `.person` to the end of the array. As well as removing the index `item` from the beginning of the array to be pushed, and changing the property names to match the sample state data given:

```js
for(var item=0; item<re.length; item++) 
{
  A.push([item, re[item].personName, re[item].businessName, re[item].date, re[item].activity, re[item].hours, re[item].learningStatement]);
}
```

Modifying the `for` loop to line up with the array indices by doing the increment at the end of each loop (i = 0 for the first iteration).

```js
for(var i=0; i < A.length; i++) 
{
  csvRow.push(A[i].join(","))
}
```

Adding a comma to the csv string so the first column does not get trimmed.

```js
a.href='data:attachment/csv.,' + csvString
```

**Full working example**

```js
function exportCsv() {
  var csvRow=[];
  var A = [['person', 'business', 'date', 'activity', 'hours', 'learningStatement']];
  var re = [
    {
      'personName': 'test',
      'businessName': 'test',
      'date': 'test',
      'activity': 'test',
      'hours': 'test',
      'learningStatement': 'test'
    }
  ];

  for(var item=0; item<re.length; item++) 
  {
    A.push([re[item].personName, re[item].businessName, re[item].date, re[item].activity, re[item].hours, re[item].learningStatement]);
  }

  for(var i=0; i < A.length; i++) 
  {
    csvRow.push(A[i].join(","))
  }
  var csvString=csvRow.join("%0A");

  var a=document.createElement("a");
  a.href='data:attachment/csv.,' + csvString; // Add a comma here otherwise it will trim the first column
  a.target='_Blank';
  a.download= 'testfile.csv';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}
```

Comment: thank you it works, but i see my data does not display in the file created, how can i make that happen? any ideas?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed a couple more things. I'll update my answer

Comment: im getting this now: This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. but it does download a file but i don't recognize it.

Comment: Hmm. I was able to download it and open it in excel. Can you see what the file extension is?

Comment: it does not show a file extension, but i did open it with notepad++ and it shows: 
business,date,activity,hours,learningStatement
test,test,test,test,test,test, why doesn't the person object show on the file?

Comment: I missed a line when I copied it into the answer. I'll fix it sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204134/discussion-between-sean-van-loggerenberg-and-brian-thompson).